# Spring, XMLCOnfiguration: Without indicating annotation in xml file how it is working?

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations

I am trying to write a spring program with using Annotation config in xml file, It is working without this configuration initiating also. I wrote method() in one file and and declared CLassPathXmlApplicationContext with Beans.xml file, I wrote a Student bean and applied the @Required annotation for setter methods, Please find the Bean configuration xml file below:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Definition for student bean -->
<bean id = "student" class = "com.tutorialspoint.Student">
  <property name = "name" value = "Zara" />
  <property name = "age"  value = "11"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

When i run this program with or without following Annotation indication in xml file, the code works fine, Please guide me the underlying reason for it.

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Comment: The question is unclear.  Are you asking why `<context:annotation-config/>` does not seem to be required?

Comment: @Jim Garrison: Yes, Without <context:annotation-config/> this, it is working fine.

Comment: I understand that you are wondering about the use of annotaion-config. So here is a [link to refer](http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan/)

Comment: Thank you for the URL. that makes sense and gives better details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Required` annotation applies to bean property setter methods and it indicates that the affected bean property must be populated in XML configuration file at configuration time.

Once `<context:annotation-config/>` is configured, you can start annotating your code to indicate that Spring should automatically wire values into properties, methods, and constructors. It does not means that some things will wrong without it when you using the `@Required`

In your xml, you have defined your properties, so the `@Required` will run well

Comment: So even if we configure <context:annotation-config/> it works when we declare @Required to properties, methods and constructors... Thank you for the information.